# Is there a better query on Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

I made a query. But I think I too much use subquery.
Do you think it is quite not bad query? or should I use different things in Django ORM functions?

```
class Like(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
[ Like ]
from_user | to_user |
    2     |    1    |
    3     |    1    |
    4     |    1    |
    5     |    1    |
    6     |    1    |
    7     |    1    |
    1     |    3    |
    1     |    4    |

[ Result ]
from_user | to_user |
    2     |    1    |
    5     |    1    |
    6     |    1    |
    7     |    1    |
```

user_id has User 1 id

```
users = User.objects.filter(
    id__in=Subquery(
        Like.objects.filter(to_user=user_id).exclude(
            from_user__in=Subquery(
                Like.objects.filter(
                    from_user=user_id,
                    to_user__in=Subquery(
                        Like.objects.filter(to_user=user_id).values('from_user')
                    )
                ).values('to_user')
            )
        ).values('from_user')
    )
)
```

And can I reuse the subquery? Because I used the same query twice.

```
Like.objects.filter(to_user=user_id)
```

If this query is used by many users, I think response speed will be very slow.

Comment: `If this query is used by many users` response size will be large. You should use pagination.

Comment: It is also a good idea. But I'm gonna limit the max user number on the list (like only showing 5 users?). I just wonder if I can less write subquery or more efficient way